# make android TextView overflow to next view

Tags: android, textview, overflow

I have a horizonal linear layout with different views. Some of these have nested textviews.
is there a way to programatically make a textview overflow the view and go over the next one without expanding  the parent's view width? Thanks a lot for your help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLSg2.jpg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want each view to be up to 40 pixels long then you put in the string you want up to that size and then move on to the next view

Here is an example for the first view

```
TextView someView = findViewById(R.id.some_view);
    String str = "This is a string that you want to put in the views";
    int i = 0;
    while(someView.getWidth() <= 40){
        someView.append(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));
        i++;
    }
```

**You need to check what to do if the string is not long enough and we run out of his bounds (just do an if statement or try and catch)**